# Ошибка. Пишет типа неожиданное двоеточее

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, localhost

Сама ошибка:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in N:\home\test1.ru\www\phpr\vendor\connect.php on line 3
Вот код:

/* <?php

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(host:'localhost', user:'root', password:'', database:'test');
if (!$connect) {
    die('Error connect to DataBase');
}
```

?> */

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь там надо `=` писать.

Comment: А каков вопрос? Исправте ошибку,

Comment: Ну а как исправить?

Comment: То что IDE показывает тебе названия аргументов - не значит что их надо в коде писать.

Comment: ну а в итоге как мне это исправить

Comment: $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test'); - может так? ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так исправить:
`$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');`

И почитать о этой функции, и о аргументах в php в целом

- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php

Comment: да ну. заработало. благодарю

Comment: да и еще почитать скинул. вообще отвал бошки

Comment: кароче спасибо!